# ASP.NET Core Razor Page: Write html content to new browser tab?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Using `HttpClient`, I make a GET request which returns a html response.

Request to url in method handler:

```
var response = string.Empty;
var result = await _httpClient.CreateClient().GetAsync(newUrl);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var bytesResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response)

  // How to open bytesResponse in a new browser tab?

}
```

Html response content from request:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

      <!-- body content -->

    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Attempting to add `await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytesResponse, 0, bytesResponse.Length);` will throw an `System.ObjectDisposedException: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.` exception

Would appreciate assistance on how to display the response in a new browser tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,if you want to open a new browser tag,it cannot be done in razor handler.It need to be done in view.You need to decorate your link with the "_blank" attribute like this:

```
<a asp-page-handler="xxxxx" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Here is a demo worked:

test.cshtml:

```
<a asp-page-handler="Html" target="_blank">link</a>
```

test.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
public ActionResult OnGetHtml()
        {
            return base.Content("<div>Hello</div>", "text/html");
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification (**it cannot be done in razor handler**) and the page process flow. This has set me in the right direction to tackle my problem.